# Problema com imagens ao buildar - Ionic 2

Tags: ionic, ionic2

tenho um projeto e está tudo nos conformes como neste link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952214/correct-way-to-use-image-assets-in-ionic-2

As imagens estão na pasta src/assets/img mas quando eu dou o build, elas não aparecem no aparelho (apenas no browser quando faço o ionic serve).

Ontem estava tudo ok, o último build que fiz aparecia direitinho... hoje, por algum motivo, elas não aparecem mais de jeito nenhum. Já apaguei as pastas e criei de novo e nada.

Já inclusive iniciei um novo projeto, copiei os arquivos e continua não mostrando.

Comment: legal cara q vc resolveu assim, to vendo q seu topico eh antigo eu estou no ionic 3 e passando por este problema, mas soh estou usando letras minusculas e nada de funcionar.
se tiver alguma outra ideia me da um toque ai. valeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muito testar, consegui resolver o problema:

Todas as minhas imagens possuiam ao menos uma letra maiúscula, e na hora de digitar o path no código, eu usava apenas caracteres minúsculos, ou seja:

O browser fazia o 'acerto' pra mim, mas o app não. Em resumo: não nomeiem suas imagens com letras maiúsculas e minusculas para evitar este tipo de confusão.